# lldb watchpoint print value and automatically continue

Tags: debugging, lldb, watchpoint

Setting a watchpoint using `(lldb) watchpoint set var myvar` will pause the program whenever the variable is written to and print out the change of value to the debugging console.

From using this in the Xcode GUI, I know that it is possible to set breakpoints that execute an action and automatically continue the program afterwards.

Is a similar behaviour possible with watchpoints? Can I set a watchpoint that only prints the change and automatically continues the program execution afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually used a solution close to what Jason described above. It worked for me in XCode 6 and is described in details there: [In XCode 6 how can you set a watchpoint without stopping execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581844/in-xcode-6-how-can-you-set-a-watchpoint-without-stopping-execution/28600716#28600716).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `watch command add` command in lldb.  The watchpoint commands are not as mature / tested as the breakpoint commands in lldb -- I just did some quick tests and what you want to do doesn't work right now with Xcode 6.  Ideally you'd do something like `watchpoint command add --script-type command -one-liner "continue"` or `watchpoint command add --script-type python -one-liner "return True"` (of course the shortest unambiguous command can be used, e.g. `wa c add -e python -o "return True"`, I'm spelling out the full commands to be clearer).  When you add a command to a watchpoint it doesn't look like the "old value / new value" output is produced.  I don't think that should be its current behavior but I'll ask a few other people to see if they strongly disagree.